# How can I highlight words in my document that are typed into a search box?

Tags: javascript, html

Im using the following code from their website

```
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <form>
    <div center class="input-field">
      <input id="search" type="search" required>
      <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
      <i class="material-icons">close</i>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</nav>
```

Is there any way to search through the website, and highlight the words when the user types them?

Comment: You can use this library. https://github.com/GerHobbelt/hilitor

Comment: @makshh - That seems to work very well, here is the example page -> http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/search-highlight/

Comment: So you can use it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hilitor.js for that.

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <form>
      <div center class="input-field">
        <input id="search" type="search" required placeholder="Search...">
        <label for="search"></label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit praesentium ad placeat voluptates perspiciatis eaque odio non nisi impedit ea. Praesentium similique perferendis animi, cumque neque placeat deserunt facere ut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit praesentium ad placeat voluptates perspiciatis eaque odio non nisi impedit ea. Praesentium similique perferendis animi, cumque neque placeat deserunt facere ut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit praesentium ad placeat voluptates perspiciatis eaque odio non nisi impedit ea. Praesentium similique perferendis animi, cumque neque placeat deserunt facere ut.</p>
```

CSS:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #fff;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
   color: #fff;  
   opacity: 1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #fff;  
}
input {
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 60px;
  background: #d66367;
  color: #fff;
}
```

JS:

```
var myHilitor2;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  myHilitor2 = new Hilitor("playground");
  myHilitor2.setMatchType("left");
}, false);

document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  myHilitor2.apply(this.value);
}, false);
```

Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQXKeL).

Don't forget to include hilitor.js.

Next time provide better topic name and tags, because your issue is not related to materialize or materializecss.

Comment: is there any way to scroll down to the first highlighted word? @makshh

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that.